# Android time picker in Cordova Application is not having option to set time

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

In my Jquery Mobile Application wrapped with codrova, I need to pop up time picker from where user picks the time. For that I am using

`<input type="time" class="add-reminder-time-picker date-picker-input" value="10:00">`

If I run the Application in Android emulator, it pop-ups the time picker dialog. But instead of having Set and Cancel button, It has only clear and Cancel button. Hence unable to set the time. I can either cancel or clear the text input.

How to change the button name and functionality ?[image]

Comment: it's an android bug https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=434695 https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79948

Comment: So should we use any plugins to incorporate time picker functionality in HTML5 based ordova Application ?

Comment: Well, I think this problem happens only on android 5, and android 5 has an updatable webview, so this problem might be solved by now, try on a device with the webview updated. If it's solved, you can assume all the users have the latest webview and this problem should not happen to them, if not, yes, you should use a native time picker plugin

Comment: Thanks. I am using Jquery Mobile DateBox plugin.